# Generator frequency control

Tags: frequency, generator

We are trying to run an AC generator on an RV for a customer. On an RV as you drive the engine RPM goes up and down. As I understand it, that would change the outlut AC frequency.

Is there an electronic device that I could use to keep the output frequency  at a steady 60 Hz?

Comment: Look at "inverter generators"

Comment: You could use a DC motor and AC gen with the field current regulated by a tach. Or x kW motor speed control Reference set to line f for high power , or just an electronic x kW inverter.  It all depends on the quality of AC sine or square and W/$ budget

Comment: There is a substantial difference in AC quality , impedance and load regulation error in the designs. So estimate specs 1st

Comment: Another possibility is to only buy appliances that can handle changing frequency. But since you said this is for a customer, I wouldn't recommend it. Way too complicated.

Answer (score 0):

If the load is a small one, an inverter from 12V is the best way to go. In fact it's the only practical solution for a varying engine RPM source.

For a larger load, you need a separate generator unit with a fixed RPM.

That said, you can still buy 120V alternators that are belt-driven intended for under-hood generation. They were popular some decades ago on utility trucks as an alternative to a separate gasoline generator. Unfortunately they require a fixed RPM from the engine, so they aren't suitable for an RV in motion.

This company sells them: https://www.fabcopower.com/generat/bgen.htm

Comment: We are using a 5000 watt inverter now to do what we want We would have to run more like a 12 to 15,000 watt unit.  Which is not practical due to the cost of a good quality inverter We would have about 9 to $10,000 invested. I would like to just run a AC generator off of the engine. I would assume somewhere out there is a controller to control the output and keep it at a steady 60Hz no matter what the output is.  I know for instance on our large TIG welders at work when we're doing AC welding with aluminum we can change the frequency anything from about 52 120 hz.

Comment: These type of TIG welders also use inverters. They output square waves vs. sine waves used for power inverters. Different animal.